# How to plot 3d coordinates in the real world into 2d coordinates of a floor plan in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I am working on a AR app using ARkit.I want to track the user.I can push the x,y and z coordinates of the user.How to map 3d points of the user location in real world into 2d floor plan.There are certain challenges because when the app is opened the user position(camera position) is x,y ,z=(0,0,0).The user position is the camera position.With respect to this how to map in the 2d floor plan.So that when the user moves around, his position can be shown in the 2D-Floor Plan.

I could add AR models and find the distance between them and the user.Will that help to find the coordinates of the user?When I turn the device the coordinates changes so we cant rely on user position(camera position) for plotting.

```
private Vector3 Campos;
public GameObject chagepos; //Added as a child of camera
private void LateUpdate()
{




//Created a starting point

Campos.x = 246f;//x-Coordinate of the floor plan
Campos.z = 121f;//y-Coordinate of the floor plan
chagepos.transform.position = new Vector3(Campos.x, 0, Campos.z);

Debug.Log(chagepos.transform.position);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the user position is represented as a Vector3, then you can just extract the x and z components to get your Vector2:

`Vector2 floorPlanPosition = new Vector2(playerPosition.x, playerPosition.z);`

You might need to reproject the floorPlanPosition into the local space of the floor plan object (since that is presumably a 3d object as well)

`Vector3 worldSpacePositionOfPlayerOnFloorplan = floorPlan.transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(floorPlanPosition.x, 0, floorPlanPosition.y);`

There are other transformations that you might need to do, i.e. if the player is not at 0,0 within the floorplan, you may need to do some subtraction of offset positions.

Comment: The user can open the app anywhere in the floorplan.If he opens the app in say point (-2,3,9)position of user in real world.How to plot that value in 2d.

Comment: You will need to subtract the starting position from the current position to get the offset position, essentially allowing you to override the zero point.

Comment: I created a starting point..which I override the coordinates of device with coordinates of the floor plan.But when I turn right and left the coordinates of the device changes.